# removing @email.com from string in php

Tags: php

I want to just get the left half of an email address ( the `username` part of `username@email.com` ), so stripping the @ and any characters after it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you have PHP5.3 you could use [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
$email = 'username@email.com';

$username = strstr($email, '@', true); //"username"
```

If not, just use the trusty `substr`

```
$username = substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
```

Comment: +1 Looking at the manual page to strstr the exact same question is solved as an example.

Answer (score 6):

```
$parts=explode('@','username@email.com');

echo $parts[0];// username
echo $parts[1];// email.com
```

Comment: @chriso: Why it is unnecessary here.

Comment: string functions are faster ;) why use arrays when you don't have to?

Answer (score 2):

you can split the string using explode()

```
$email = 'hello@email.com';
/*split the string bases on the @ position*/
$parts = explode('@', $email);
$namePart = $parts[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody's used `preg_match` yet:

```
<?php
    $email = 'user@email.com';
    preg_match('/(\S+)(@(\S+))/', $email, $match);

/*  print_r($match);
        Array
        (
            [0] => user@email.com
            [1] => user
            [2] => @email.com
            [3] => email.com
        )
*/

    echo $match[1];  // output: `user`
?>
```

Using an array means if you decide later that you want the `email.com` part, you've already got it separated out and don't have to drastically change your method. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function subStrEmail($Useremail)
{
    $emailSub=substr($Useremail,4);
    $email = explode('.', $emailSub);

    if($email[0]=='www'){
        $email=substr($emailSub,4);
        $email=ltrim($email,'www.');
        return $email;
    }
    return $emailSub;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -3):

```
$text = 'abc@email.com';
$text = str_replace('@email.com','',$text);
```

Comment: I doubt he's going to **already** know the `@email.com` part and **not** know the `username` part..

Comment: in that case EXPLODE is the best option, though it can be done with looping through all the list, and sub-stringing it !!!